# Xcode 4 post installation problem

Tags: macos, install, mac-appstore, xcode

I have successfully installed Xcode 4.1 from Mac AppStore on Lion, and restarted the machine to be sure that everything will run correctly, everything is ok up to this point. however, when I open Applications (and also when I open LaunchPad too), there is no XCode there, there is an icon named: "install XCode" (its size = XCode size = 3.5 GB, and contains a lot of packages inside it). I can run XCode without problems using either its icon on the dock or from spotlight.
my questions are:

1) where is the real XCode Icon located ?

2) what is the correct way to remove "install XCode" package icon that exists in Applications?

3) can I put the "install XCode" package on a USB stick and install it on another machine (running Lion of course) without problems?

thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a bit confusing, but you didn't actually install Xcode 4. What you did was installing the Xcode 4 installer. So what you got to do is:

1. Open the Install Xcode-app located in your launchpad.
2. Make sure iTunes is closed, this is necessary, and the installer won't check for this.
3. Finalize the setup (well, Lion will do this for you, just press the buttons).
4. Optionally, restart your Mac.
5. Optionally, remove the Install Xcode-app.

It'll probably prompt you that it's moving your existing Developer-folder to Developer Old so it can install Xcode 4.1 to /Developer/.

Answer (score 0):

Both the above are correct:

Apple's App Store uses pretty confusing terminology. After you purchase/download an app, App Store marks it as "installed" when, in fact it's only been downloaded. The installer will be in your "Applications" folder and will then need to be run to actualy install the software.

Just to add to the confusion, Xcode installs into a "Developer" folder at the root of your hard drive, not into the "Applications" folder. So, in summary; "installed" means "downloaded", downloads go into "Applications" not "Downloads" and [in the case of Xcode] the installed application doesn't end up in the "Applications" folder.

Sometimes Apple has very strange notions as to what constitutes user-friendliness!

BTW - Installers downloaded from the App Store are automatically deleted, after they've been run. To avoid this [for example, if you want to install a downloaded app on more than one computer] it's a good idea to copy the installer to another location first, to prevent this "auto-delete" behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

1. It's in `/Developer/Applications/`
2. Not sure what you mean.
3. Likely.